# Grass projection issue

Tags: coordinate-system, classification, grass-7.0

I am working with GRASS and I am trying to do a supervised classification. The issue here is that I get an error for NaN values.

> ERROR: Not enough data points

Now I know that is an error that you get, most of the times, when the projection is different and because I know that I re-projected all of my data in GGRS87 (I have both vector and raster data) but I still get the same error. What should I do? Should I try another projection or is there another way to do supervised classification.

P.S I tried with this tutorial https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_classification#Supervised_classification

and I tried to create a raster map from CORINE2000

`g.region vect=corine align=raster
v.to.rast in=corine out=corine_training use=attr col=CODE labelcol=CODE2 --o`

And now I can't generate statistics using

```
i.gensigset group=OB subgroup=raster_maps sig=corine_smap training=corine_training
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So researching for my issue I came across an old github repository filled with lectures on how to do a Supervised Classification

https://github.com/FOSS4GAcademy/GST105FOSS4GLabs/blob/master/Module%206%20Lab/QGIS%202.4%20and%20GRASS%206.4.4/Module%206%20Lab.md

Which actually helped me retrace my steps and solve my problem.